# Many-to-many relationship on common column (not on primary keys)

Tags: jpa, many-to-many, playback, ebean

I am trying to map tables to entities using jpa and ebean. I have two tables those have one common column:

```
Table Phone:
-id
-number
-area
```

```
Table Client:
-id
-name
-area
```

I have to add between them many-to-many relationship (one phone belongs to many clients, one client can have multiple phones), but based on the same `area` field.

```
@Entity
public class Phone extends Model {
   @Id
   private long id;
   @NotNull
   private String number;
   @NotNull
   private String area;

   @ManyToMany
       @JoinTable(name = "phone_client",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "phone_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
   private List<Client> clients; 

   // getters and setters
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Client extends Model {
   @Id
   private long id;
   @NotNull
   private String name;
   @NotNull
   private String area; 

   // getters and setters
}
```

I have been trying `@JoinTable`, `@JoinColumn`, `@Where`(but it requires static content) and without any result. I am out of ideas how it can be implemented or it's even possible. I will be grateful for any clue.

**Edit**
Maybe description it's a little bit unclear. 
`Phone.clients` should point to the list of `Clients` with the same `area`.

```
phone.area = client.area
```

Comment: It is indeed a bit unclear what you are asking. My guess is that you are trying to _limit_ the contents of the `Phone.clients` list to only those `Client` objects that have the saem `area` as the `Phone`. _Right?_

Comment: Yes, exactly. `Phone.clients` should point to the clients that have the same `area`.